# Symlink .git/logs is removed when running git rebase command on Windows

Tags: git, repo

I'm running git and repo on a Windows 10 PC.
Git has been downloaded from https://git-scm.com/download/win, python from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/, repo from our internal repository. The details of the tools can be found below.

```sh
$ repo --version
repo version v2.4.1-9-g910dfe8
       (from C:\Users\KNG1LUD\bin\git-repo\.git)
repo launcher version 2.4
       (from C:\Users\KNG1LUD\bin\git-repo\repo)
       (currently at 2.4.1-9-g910dfe8)
repo User-Agent git-repo/2.4.1-9-g910dfe8 (Win32) git/2.29.2.windows.1 Python/3.6.0
git 2.29.2.windows.1
git User-Agent git/2.29.2.windows.1 (Win32) git-repo/2.4.1-9-g910dfe8
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
OS Windows 10 (10.0.17763)
CPU AMD64 (Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel)
```

- Symbolic links are enabled

```
$ git config --list | grep symlink
core.symlinks=true
```

I'm getting the following error when updating my workspace with 'repo sync' in a cmd or git-bash shell on Windows after downloading and rebasing an outdated change in one of my git.
There is no way to get rid of the error without deleting the .git/logs directory in the affected git.

- The error

```
D:\ws\support\r-sync\my-project-path>repo sync .
Fetching project xx/yy/zz
Fetching projects: 100% (1/1)
Fetching projects: 100% (1/1), done.
error: logs is different in D:/ws/support/r-sync/my-project-path\.git vs D:/ws/support/r-sync/.repo/projects/my-project-path.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\main.py", line 547, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\main.py", line 522, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\main.py", line 184, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\subcmds\sync.py", line 840, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\project.py", line 1379, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync, submodules=submodules)
  File "C:\git-tools\git-repo\project.py", line 2578, in _InitWorkTree
    raise e
error.GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree. If you're comfortable with the possibility of losing the work tree's git metadata, use `repo sync --force-sync my-project-path` to proceed.
```

- How to reproduce it
- In a cmd or git-bash shell on Windows 10, run the following commands

```
repo init --no-repo-verify -u ssh://<my-gerrit-server>/<my-manifest-git> -b <my-branch>
repo sync xx/yy/zz
cd <my-project-path>
repo download xx/yy/zz XX/Y
git rebase origin/master
repo sync .
```

My investigation shows that the problem starts at the 'git rebase origin/master' step. As soon as the git rebase command is run,
the symlink '`logs`' under `.\my-project-path\.git` is removed and replaced by a plain directory with the same name.

The result of this disconnection between `.\my-project-path\.git\logs` and `.\.repo\projects\my-project-path.git\logs` is the sync error:

```
error: logs is different in D:/ws/support/r-sync/my-project-path\.git 
                         vs D:/ws/support/r-sync/.repo/projects/my-project-path.git
```

Has anyone had the same problem?
Do you know why the symlink 'logs' was removed?
And lastly how to prevent that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Windows `rmdir()` equivalent behaves differently from POSIX ones, in that when used on a symbolic link that points at a directory, the target directory gets removed, which has been corrected with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021).

See [commit 3e7d488](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e7d4888e5b83f1ed75667ff557b8996f427adf0) (02 Aug 2021) by [Thomas Bétous (`thombet`)](https://github.com/thombet).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 099a64a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/099a64aa3943ba1eb9e0bd5ea20923820c29c95a), 04 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e7d4888e5b83f1ed75667ff557b8996f427adf0): align symlinks-related `rmdir()` behavior with Linux
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Bétous</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When performing a rebase, `rmdir()` is called on the folder `.git/logs`.
>
> On Unix, `rmdir()` exits without deleting anything, in case `.git/logs` is a symbolic link.
> But the equivalent functions on Windows (`_rmdir`, `_wrmdir` and `RemoveDirectoryW`) do not behave the same and **remove the folder if it is symlinked even if it is not empty**.
>
> This creates issues when folders in `.git/` are symlinks which is especially the case when `git-repo` <sup>(1)</sup> is used: It replaces `.git/logs/` with a symlink.
>
> One such issue is that the *target* of that symlink is removed e.g. during a [`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e7d4888e5b83f1ed75667ff557b8996f427adf0/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup>, where `delete_reflog("REBASE_HEAD")` will not only try to remove `.git/logs/REBASE_HEAD` but then recursively try to remove the parent directories until an error occurs, a technique that obviously relies on `rmdir()` refusing to remove a symlink.
>
> This was reported in [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2967](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2967).
>
> This commit updates `mingw_rmdir()` so that its behavior is the same as Linux `rmdir()` in case of symbolic links.
>
> To verify that Git does not regress on the reported issue, this patch adds a regression test for the `git rebase` symptom, even if the same `rmdir()` behavior is quite likely to cause potential problems in other Git commands as well.
>
> <sup>(1)</sup>: `git-repo` is a python tool built on top of Git which helps manage many Git repositories.
> It stores all the `.git/` folders in a central place by taking advantage of symbolic links.
> More information: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/